# Automate activation account via link in email

Tags: automation, token, soapui, activation

When register to our app, the server send an activation mail that include link with token on it to activate the user account.
I'm using soapui to automate the server side, and i'm looking for a way to get this email and activate the account without doing it manually. 
Any idea's?
(for the testing we can use gmail acconts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The (main parts of) the activation mail have to be in your database somewhere. Read that using a JDBC step, if you have the -Pro version. Or you will have to do it in Groovy if you only have the free version.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently implemented using JDBC test step by connecting to DB instance and doing a select statement for the user and pulled out the activation code, passing it to activation API call and its Successful.